# Why is my exception not caught by the Laravel destroy method?

Tags: laravel, destroy

Why is my exception not caught?

```
    try {
        \Account::destroy($id);
        return Redirect::to("/manager/account")
                            ->with("success_message", "Item excluido com sucesso");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Redirect::to("/manager/account/{$id}/edit")
                        ->with("error_message", "Erro ao excluir item");
    }
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`imob_io`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_account_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from
>   `accounts` where `id` = 2)

Comment: Try catching `\Exception` instead of `Exception`

Comment: Ouch....!! Namespace!! thank´s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you are catching the class `Exception` inside your current namespace. Instead you should refer to the global type `\Exception`:

```
catch (\Exception $e){
    return Redirect::to("/manager/account/{$id}/edit")
                    ->with("error_message", "Erro ao excluir item");
}
```

I also recommend you narrow it down a bit instead of just catching every exception. For example you could catch `QueryException` which will be thrown for constraint violations etc.

```
catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
```